# How to not include a set of results in result without using a where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently use 4 tables to get the extract of data, i them remove some of the rows in excel. Is there a way where i can add a condition in select statement without manipulating the where clause.
Ex:

```
Results
Supplier    Product & extra
Sky         Broadband & mobile minutes
Sky         fiber broadband & internet security
TalkTalk    Simply broadband & mobile minutes
EE          Unlimited broadband & mobile minutes
EE          fiber broadband & international minutes
```

Tbl1 provides suppliers info, tbl2 provides product info and tbl3 provides extra info.
I need to remove EE with mobile minutes info from results while keeping the rest of EE. I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `WHERE` clause? This is what the `WHERE` clause is for. Your criteria is a bit vague, but it sounds like you would want `WHERE NOT (Supplier = 'EE' and ProductExtra LIKE '%mobile minutes%')`. If you just don't like the word `WHERE` you could probably add this to one of the JOIN predicates.

Comment: Can you show your query? Maybe it's possible to add a condition to the `JOIN` between the tables

Comment: I already have a where clause which is pulling all the suppliers, products and extras data. Wouldn't adding this requirement in where clause clash with the other requirement?

Comment: my where clauses is something like this "WHERE
      Extra IN (30, 44, 106, 107, 29, 68)
      AND serviceProvider IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 143, 149, 154, 159, 165, 167, 166, 168, 176, 177)

Comment: You can just wrap the existing WHERE clause in parentheses, append `AND` and append your filtering condition and that's it.

Comment: thank you everyone for helping me out with this query. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> my where clauses is something like this "WHERE Extra IN (30, 44, 106,
>   107, 29, 68) AND serviceProvider IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 143, 149, 154, 159,
>   165, 167, 166, 168, 176, 177)

if EE had the id of 143 and mobile minutes had the id of 106 you could just add a NOT to your existing WHERE clause. Your WHERE clause would then become:

```
WHERE Extra IN (30, 44, 106, 107, 29, 68)
AND serviceProvider IN (1, 2, 3, 10, 143, 149, 154, 159, 165, 167, 166, 168, 176, 177)
AND NOT (Extra = 106 AND serviceProvider = 143)
```

obviously changing it to use the correct id for extra and service provider.

Comment: i do need those extra and the provider, I just dont need them for a specific package.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot limit your number of rows in the select, but if you do not want to use WHERE, you can add your conditions in your JOIN (i.e. FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.col = T2.col and T2.my_col = 'smth')

Lidia D.